# How can I unit test a method with database access?

Tags: unit-testing

I have already had some difficulties on unit tests and I am trying to learn it while using a small project I currently am working on and I ran into this problem these two problems that I hope you can help me with

1- My project is an MVC project. At which level should my unit tests start? They should focus only on the business layer? Should they also test actions on my controllers?

2- I have a method that verifies an username format and then access the DB to check if it is available for use. The return is a boolean whether this username is available or not. 
Would one create a unit test for such a method? 
I would be interested on testing the format verification, but how would I check them without querying the DB? Also, if the formats are correct, but the username is already in use, I will get a false value, but the validation worked. I could decouple this method, but the DB verification should only happen if the format is correct, so they should somehow be tied.
How would someone with unit tests knowledge solve this issue. Or how would someone refactor this method to be able to test it?
I could create a stub for the DB access, but how would I attach it to my project on the user testing but detach it when running locally?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your specific case, one easy thing you could do is decompose your verification method into 3 different methods: one to check formatting, one to check DB availability, and one to tie them both together. This would allow you to test each of the sub-functions in isolation.

In more complex scenarios, other techniques may be useful. In essence, this is where [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and [inversion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) come in handy (unfortunately, those phrases mean different things to different people, but getting the basic ideas is usually a good start).

Your goal should be to decouple the concept of "Check if this username is available" from the **implementation** of checking the DB for it.

So, instead of this:

```
public class Validation
{
    public bool CheckUsername(string username)
    {
        bool isFormatValid = IsFormatValid(username);
        return isFormatValid && DB.CheckUsernameAvailability(username);
    }
}
```

You could do something like this:

```
public class Validation
{
    public bool CheckUsername(string username,
                              IUsernameAvailabilityChecker checker)
    {
        bool isFormatValid = IsFormatValid(username);
        return isFormatValid && checker.CheckUsernameAvailability(username);
    }
}
```

And then, from your unit test code, you can create a custom `IUsernameAvailabilityChecker` which does whatever you want for testing purposes. On the other hand, the actual production code can use a different implementation of `IUsernameAvailabilityChecker` to *actually* query the database.

Keep in mind that there are many, *many* techniques to solve this kind of testing problem, and the examples I gave are simple and contrived.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way I can automatically change implementation (mock/not-mocking) depending if it is a unit-test or really running on my machine?

Comment: @Oscar: Of course. The point of dependency injection is that the **calling code** is what determines what you do. When you're writing unit tests, pass a mock `IUsernameAvailabilityChecker` to the function. When you're actually calling it from your MVC Controller (or wherever), create and pass in a _real_ `IUsernameAvailabilityChecker` which accesses the database.

Answer (score 1):

Testing against outside services can be done using mocking. If you've done a good job using interfaces it's very easy to mock various parts of your application. These mocks can be injected into your unit and used like it would normally handle it.

You should start unit testing as soon as possible. If your application is not complete or code needed for testing is absent you can still test against some interface you can mock.

*On a sidenote: Unit testing is about testing behavior and is not an effective way to find bugs. You will find bugs with testing but it should not be your goal.*

For instance:

```java
interface UserService {
    public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository);
    public boolean isUsernameAvailable(String username);
}


class MyUserService implements UserService {
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public vois setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public boolean isUsernameAvailable(String username) {
        return userRepository.checkUsernameAvailability(username);
    }
}


interface UserRepository {
    public boolean checkUsernameAvailability(String username);
}

// The mock used for testing
class MockUserRepository {
    public boolean checkUsernameAvailability(String username) {
        if ("john".equals(username)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

class MyUnitTest {
    public void testIfUserNotAvailable() {
        UserService service = new UserService();    
        service.setUserRepository(new MockUserRepository);

        assertFalse(service.isUsernameAvailable('john')); // yep, it's in use
    }

    public void testIfUserAvailable() {
        UserService service = new UserService();    
        service.setUserRepository(new MockUserRepository);

        assertTrue(service.isUsernameAvailable('mary')); // yep, is available
    }
}
```